# React Axios get '401 (Unauthorized)' with a POST request

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm sorry I'm starting with react and I have a 401 error (Unauthorized)
I created a form with React Form and when I click on Sent my request returns me 401 (Unauthorized), but if I click a second time everything goes as expected

I don't understand why it doesn't work the first time I click but the second time it works

Thanks for your time

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import env from 'react-dotenv'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

function Login() {
  let history = useHistory()
  const [emailValue, setEmailValue] = useState('')
  const [passwordValue, setPasswordValue] = useState('')
  const [error, setError] = useState(false)
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState(false)
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm()
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    setEmailValue(e.email)
    setPasswordValue(e.password)
    postLogin()
  }

  function postLogin() {
    axios
      .post(env.API_URL + '/login', {
        email: emailValue,
        password: passwordValue,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        setError(false)
        const apiResponse = response.data
        localStorage.setItem('evelencia_login', JSON.stringify(apiResponse))
        history.push('/status')
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setError(true)
        setErrorMessage(error)
      })
  }

  // async function postLogin() {
  // try {
  // const response = await axios.post(env.API_URL + '/login', {
  // email: emailValue,
  // password: passwordValue,
  // })
  // setError(false)
  // const apiResponse = await response.data
  // localStorage.setItem('evelencia_login', JSON.stringify(apiResponse))
  // history.push('/status')
  // } catch (error) {
  // setError(true)
  // setErrorMessage(error)
  // }
  // }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <label>
          Email :<input type='email' {...register('email')} />
        </label>
        <label>
          Password :<input type='password' {...register('password')} />
        </label>
        <input type='submit' value='Connexion' />
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

I tried an async await function and without success
I tried some tests with Postman and everything went well

Answer (score 0):

Can you use axios post function with 3 parameters like that:

```
axios
  .post(env.API_URL + '/login', {
    email: emailValue,
    password: passwordValue,
  },
  {
   headers: {
       Content-Type: application/json
   }
  })
```

Also you should check if there is an authentication mechanism that uses header parameters like bearer etc with Postman.

Comment: I tried with a third parameter no change. 
On postman and my api does not require authentication mechanism

Answer (score 0):

*You can add another parameter in your header of your token:*

````
  .post(env.API_URL + '/login', {
    email: emailValue,
    password: passwordValue,
  },
  {
   headers: {
       Content-Type: application/json,
       Token : 'Token '+ token_value
   }
  })```
````